How do I disable logging on OkHttp okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform class, coming from OkHttpLoggingInterceptor?
How do I disable logging on OkHttp okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform class, coming from OkHttpLoggingInterceptor ?
I get log messages , that I am unable to turn off from config in host.json .   They look like this:
okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log

I get 2 log messages per instantiation of each Trigger in my azure function app.
If I get rid of the HttpLoggingInterceptor on my OkHttp client, then the log messages go away but there is no other way I can find to suppress them.
This may be related to a very old unanswered question here: How to disable okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log from printing on my console while executing the watson assistant's functionalities using java?
This is my host.json log config:
"logLevel": {
  "default": "Information",
  "Worker": "None",
  "Function": "None",
  "Function.2TriggerName": "Debug",
  "Function.1TriggerName": "Debug",
  "Function.GetHealthCheck": "None",
  "Host.Results": "Error",
  "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
  "Host.Executor": "Information",
  "Host.Triggers": "Information",
  "Azure": "Error",
  "Azure.Security.KeyVault": "Error",
  "Azure.Core.Http": "Error",
  "Azure.Storage.Blob": "Error",
  "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus": "Error",
  "Microsoft": "Error",
  "Microsoft.Identity": "Error"
},


To disable logging in OkHttp when using OkHttpLoggingInterceptor,
configure the logging level of OkHttpLoggingInterceptor by setting it to NONE or Body via code configuration.
Code Snippet:
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(); 
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.None);
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY); // or other levels 
clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

I have configured logging Interceptor in Azure function as below:
public HttpResponseMessage run(
       @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
       final ExecutionContext context) {
       context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
       HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
       loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build();
        context.getLogger().info("OkHttpClient configured with logging.");
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("OkHttpClient configured").build();
    }

Response:
Functions:

        HttpTriggerJava: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTriggerJava

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-09-03T09:27:16.133Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2024-09-03T09:27:19.225Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-09-03T09:28:03.682Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTriggerJava' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=c6be6f26-2ce6-4f33-b57a-2b5b25d55246)
[2024-09-03T09:28:03.926Z] Java HTTP trigger processed a request.
[2024-09-03T09:28:04.158Z] OkHttpClient configured with logging.
[2024-09-03T09:28:04.168Z] Function "HttpTriggerJava" (Id: c6be6f26-2ce6-4f33-b57a-2b5b25d55246) invoked by Java Worker
[2024-09-03T09:28:04.332Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTriggerJava' (Succeeded, Id=c6be6f26-2ce6-4f33-b57a-2b5b25d55246, Duration=692ms)


